# Which entity does a cross-reference refer?

Tags: xtext

If I have the following input

```
test = 3; //first
test = test + 3; //second
```

parsed with a grammar that looks like this (for example)

```
Declaration:
    name=ID "=" DeclarationContent
;

    DeclarationContent:
        number=INT ("+" DeclarationContent)?
        | reference=[Declaration] ("+" DeclarationContent)?
    ;
```

to which declaration does the reference refer (looking at the second declaration in my example)? Or in other words does the reference `"test"` (second Declaration) refer to the first Declaration `("test = 3;")` or directly to itself `("test = test+ 3")` and would therefor be a cycle in hierarchy.

Greeting Krzmbrzl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xtext will always link a cross reference `[Declaration]` to the first elemenent which is identified by the given `ID`. In your example `hello + 3`, the cross reference behind `hello` will resolved to the declaration `hello` in line 1. But if you have *more then one element* with the *same (qualified) name* within the **same scope** (container of visibility) Xtext will throw an Exception. You should

1. implement your own ScopeProvider (Use the generated stub in `your.dsl.scoping.YourDslScopeProvider`) to resolve this problem or
2. Use the composed check to automatically validate names.

   ```
   fragment = validation.JavaValidatorFragment auto-inject {
       composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
   }
   ```